# How to compare value between two column in one row, if different then create another row?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have the following table in MySQL:

```
id | item_id | uom | uom1
1    1         kg    box
```

When i select all from the table, it will display one row.

I want to make it to display two row if the uom and uom1 is different.

For example, uom = kg and uom1 = box then result will show

```
id | item_id | uom
1    1         kg
2    1         box
```

if both uom and uom1 is same(kg) then only one row will show

```
id | item_id | uom
1    1         kg
```

Is it possible to do it using sql? Then i will just loop it at my view.

Comment: In your example, both the id can't be `1`, also, do you want to update your table with a new row?

Comment: @Saurabh sorry, typo for id. Yes, i will store the data by using indication to determine whether is uom or uom1

Comment: seems word in topic "create" should be changed ... to "show" or similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way of doing it would be

```
select id, item_id, uom from tbl union
select id, item_id, uom1 from tbl
```

`UNION` will by default filter out duplicate lines. There is no need for further "tricks" ...

@Neeraj Wadhwa suggested the second line to be changed to:

```
select id, item_id, uom1 as uom from tbl
```

This is possible and will produce the same result, but it is not really necessary. The column names in a `UNION` construct will be determined by the first select statement anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
  @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS id,
  T.* 
from (
    select  `item_id`, `uom`
    from Table1

    union

    select  `item_id`, `uom1` as `uom`
    from Table1
) T , (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

---

```
| id | item_id | uom |
|----|---------|-----|
|  1 |       1 |  kg |
|  2 |       1 | box |
```

---

[DEMO SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/992aca/10/0)

Comment: Union is required instead of Union All.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple union should help here:

```
select distinct * from (
  select id, item, uom1 as uom from stuff
    union
  select id, item, uom2 as uom from stuff
  ) as unionised
order by unionised.id
```

Hre's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ece687/1